# Java 8 stream filter for Map<String, List<Object>>

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

I'm facing issues when I try to use stream to process a Map.
I have :

```
Class Person {
  public String name;
  public String ID;
}
```

And 2 different Maps (same structure but contains different elements):

```
Map<String, List<Person>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("group1", new Person("abc", "12345"));
map1.put("group2", new Person("def", "23456"));
```

And

```
Map<String, List<Person>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("group3", new Person("asd", "12345"));
```

What I want to do is using stream to process these 2 map, and filter out Map<String, List> which only satisfy my given conditions, e.g. if Person has same ID, merge it and keep first name.
For above example, result should be:

```
{group1,("abc", "12345")}
{group2,("def", "23456")}
```

This is my current implementation:

```
Map<String, List<Person>> result = map1.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getValue().stream().allMatch(e -> e.getID() !=
                        map2.entrySet().stream().flatMap(it -> it.getValue().stream().forEach(y -> y.getID()))))
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

I'm not familiar with Stream, any help are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your map is id to list of persons, however you are putting a single person into it. What exactly are the data structures?

Comment: that's not a ID, just a group name

Comment: In `map1` you're using the same key for the same map but for a different person.  And the value type is `List<Person>`.  You need to show your exact before and after requirements.  And if your not familiar with streams, why not use other approaches.

Comment: without stream I need to use loop to process these 2 maps, guess that's pretty time consuming?  what I want to do is merge these 2 maps, and make sure I don't have Person with same ID after merge

Comment: @HaoR in the question you have defined `map1` as `Map<String, List<Person>>`. But `map1.put("group1", new Person("abc", "12345"));` this statement would only compile if your map is `Map<String, Person>`

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like the following?

```
    Map<String, List<Person>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("group1", new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Person("abc", "12345"))));
    map1.put("group2", new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Person("def", "23456"))));

    Map<String, List<Person>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("group3", new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Person("asd", "12345"))));

    Map<String, List<Person>> mergedMap = new HashMap<>(map1);
    for (Entry<String, List<Person>> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
        for (Person p2 : entry.getValue()) {
            boolean sameIdFound = map1.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .anyMatch(e1 -> e1.getValue().stream().anyMatch(p1 -> p1.getId().equals(p2.getId())));
            if (! sameIdFound) {
                mergedMap.computeIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), k -> new ArrayList<>())
                        .add(p2);
            }
        }
    }
    
    mergedMap.forEach((g, pl) -> System.out.println(g + " -> " + pl));
```

Output:

> ```
> group2 -> [23456=def]
> group1 -> [12345=abc]
> ```

I first create a new map identical to `map1` (shallow copy, you probably want a deeper copy, leaving that to you for now). Next for each person somewhere in `map2` I check if a person with the same ID already exists in `map1`. If not, I insert it with the group and name from `map2`.